# Unexpected characters in lex parsing on macOS

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I am currently working on a simple Lex+Yacc parser for a SCSS subset, but while on my Linux machine the lexical analyzer seems to work perfectly, on a macOS Catalina machine it gives an "unexpected character: -61" error when parsing whitespace/newline on input as simple as `a { }`.

In other words, it seems like some character of this expression, such as some whitespace I am unaware of, is not accepted by the regexes above, or some buffer is not properly initialized for reasons I can't find.

To make things even weirder, this happens only if the input is manually typed fast, whereas leaving ~1s breaks between pressing keys makes it accept it without issues. Do you have any idea of what may be causing it?

Extensive research has not helped me solving this issue, thus I am asking here. Thank you in advance.

This is the whole code of my parser so far, in case it helps:

```
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

%}

DIGIT       [0-9]
NUM         {DIGIT}+(\.{DIGIT}+)?
LETTER      [a-zA-Z]
ID          ({LETTER}|_)({LETTER}|{DIGIT}|\-|_)*
COMMENT     \/\/.*\n
UNIT        (px|em|\%)


%%

\@SYMTAB    {print_variables();} // DEBUG
\/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/ ECHO; // /**/ comments are echo-d to output
[ \v\t\n\r\f] {} // ignore whitespace
{COMMENT}   {} // ignore comments of type "//"

"+"         {return T_PLUS;}
"-"         {return T_MINUS;}
"*"         {return T_STAR;} 
"/"         {return T_DIV;}     
"("         {return T_PL;}
")"         {return T_PR;}     
"{"         {return T_BL;}
"}"         {return T_BR;}
":"         {return T_COLON;}
";"         {return T_SEMICOLON;} 
","         {return T_COMMA;}
">"         {return T_GT;}
"."         {return T_DOT;}
"#"         {return T_HASH;}

{UNIT}      {yylval.string = strdup(yytext);  return UNIT;}

{NUM}       {yylval.number = atof(yytext); return NUM;}


\${ID}      {
            char* name = strdup(yytext); 
            SYMREC* s = get_variable(name);
            if(s == 0) {
                  s = create_variable_table(name);
            }
            yylval.sym = s;
            return VAR;}

{ID}        {yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return ID;}


.           { printf("!!! ERROR Unexpected character: %d !!!\n", yytext[0]); return yytext[0]; }

%%
```

Comment: `a` in hexadecimal is `61`.  Have you tried piping input into your program from a file?

Comment: @david: the character is being printed with `%d`, not `%x`, and the `-` is significant.

Answer (score 0):

`-61` is hexadecimal `C3`, which is the first byte in a multibyte UTF-8 sequence for a character whose codepoint is in the range 192-255. So you are accidentally typing some character but we can't tell which one because we'd need to see the second byte.

Most accented letters are in this range, for what it's worth. Perhaps you accidentally entered `á` instead of `a`.

It's usually better to print unrecognised characters with a printf format like `0x%02X`, but that won't actually give you more information; it just presents it in a more common form.

Comment: It was a strange whitespace character used by macOS on alt+space. Thank you!